# Best practice for saving 10 values : Shared Preferences with or without JSONObject?

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

I have 10 values (int and boolean) which I want to save, so I can load them whenever I need them (I need the different values at the same time which makes it easy). Is it overkill if I make one JSONString/(JSONObject) out of 10 values and save that string in SharedPreferences? Is it better practice to just store every single value like this:

> ```
> editor.putInt("Volume", VolumeBar.getProgress());
> editor.putInt("Difficulty", DifficultyBar.getProgress());
> [...]
> ```

and to get it from SharedPreferences like this:

```
Volume = mPrefs.getInt("Volume", maxVolume);
Difficulty = mPrefs.getInt("Difficulty", 0);
```

Comment: Making the String takes time, parsing it takes time...simple is usually the best way...even (and especially) if it does not appear clever. 10 values is not going to break anything. code it both ways and see what is fastest.

Comment: @JonGoodwin I´ve been searching how to see how fast a piece of code is to compare both but I can´t find anything on the internet for Android Studio. Can you tell me more about it, please?I have already another JSONString in SharedPreferences which contains some objects and I noticed that when the device´s memory is low, my Handler method (which activates a function after some time) doesn´t work. In combination with both circumstances, you would say that getting/saving 10 values to SharedPreferences shouldn´t be a problem, right?

Comment: @JonGoodwin Do you mean I should use LogCat to see what is faster?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to create model with ten variables and convert it 
 to JsonString  because you just put one strng value in SharedPref but it's issue that if you want to update one of it's values you have to retrieve the whole object and modify and set it back in sharedPref